# How to set log4net log in file if it couldn't write in the dataBase?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I know it's possible to log in both file and database and also in [more than one resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372435/configure-log4net-to-write-to-multiple-files),but is there any way to configure log4net if it failed to log in the database it log to the file automatically?

Comment: @DeanWard in his answer,he said: "I don't think you can do this by configuration.", and he is not sure is it possible or not, let this question be open until it's real answer.

Comment: Gah, I linked to the wrong answer - there's a [`FallbackAppender`](https://code.google.com/p/log4netcontrib/wiki/FallbackAppender) that you should investigate. Sorry, I'll remove my dupe flag...

Comment: You could write a wrapper for log4net, which checks for some database error (connection down, access problems etc), then log to file, otherwise log to database.